# Javascript rating scale of 1-10 is not displaying proper 'if/else' response

Tags: javascript

I am extremely green in Javascript, but I am wanting to learn it in order to be a better asset to my company.  I have been on Code Academy doing their tutorials, and I have hit a wall that I can't find an answer to on their Q & A pages, nor have I found one here.

What I am trying to do is establish a rating scale of 1-10, where anything that is an 8, or below gives one comment.  And anything that is 9 or 10, gives a different one.  Looking around on Stack I have seen a lot of people posting about a star rating, and how to utilize that, but I wasn't able to really utilize that for my purpose.  I did find one where a poster had asked a similar question as mine, but the question was closed with no responses ([JS if . . . else if statements rating from 1 - 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189120/js-if-else-if-statements-rating-from-1-10)).

The issue at hand is that no matter how I have defined the statements, I will always see both the 'if' and 'else' responses.  In my limited knowledge of Javascript, I SHOULD only see one, or another, and not both, regardless of the numerical rating. Granted, I can get the code to print out the 'if' statement if I tell it that anything over a 9 counts, but I need the code to only accept 1-10 parameters; and that in turn allows me to make my 'else' statement to print anything at an 8, or below correctly (but, again, I need this to scale from 1-10, exclusively).

Sorry about the wall of text, but basically, I need to know how I can make a rating system of 1-10, that hard stops at 1, or 10, and that prints the proper response based of a result of either 9, 10; or an 8 and below.

Here's the code so far:

```
{
    var feedback = Number( prompt("Please rate this game from 1 - 10."));

    if (feedback = 10)
    {
        console.log("Thank you!  We should race at the next concert!");
    }
    else (feedback <=8)
    {
        console.log("I'll keep practicing coding and racing.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things wrong with your code:

```
if (feedback == 10)
{
    console.log("Thank you!  We should race at the next concert!");
}
else if (feedback <=8)
{
    console.log("I'll keep practicing coding and racing.");
}
```

When you use a single `=` it is assigning the value 10 to the variable `feedback` instead of checking for equality. The value you assign to `feedback` then passes through and is evaluated in the `if` statement (the number 10 in this case). Since 10 is a `truthy` value (see http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) the `if` statement is always true. It's the same as if you said `if(10) { ...`.

Also, you need an `if` after your `else`. The reason the second code block runs is because without the `if` after `else`, the condition (`feedback <= 8`) is just a boolean statement, then the following code block in braces `{ }` runs because the `else` has completed.

Here's an updated version that I think might serve you better:

```
var feedback = Number( prompt("Please rate this game from 1 - 10."));
while(feedback < 1 || feedback > 10) {
  feedback = Number( prompt("Please enter a number from 1 - 10."));
}

if (feedback >= 9)
{
    console.log("Thank you!  We should race at the next concert!");
}
else
{
    console.log("I'll keep practicing coding and racing.");
}
```

Comment: Dude.  This does exactly what I wanted it to do, thanks a ton.  If you don't mind, me asking:  What is the purpose of || ?

Comment: || is a boolean `or` operator. It takes two arguments and if either of operands is truthy, the expression is true. The expression `feedback < 1 || feedback > 10` is true when either feedback is less than 1, or it is greater than 10, or both. Thus, if the user enters an invalid number less than 1 or greater than 10, it prompts again.

Comment: || is more complicated than just that though. You can use || to conditionally assign things. for instance, if I have a variable `var x = null` and I want to assign `var y = x`, but with a fallback in case `x` is null, I can simply write `var y = x || 10`.  It will either be assigned the value of x, or if x is falsey, it will be assigned 10.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Clint.  I especially appreciate the ELI5 answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want one console log if the response is 9 - 10 and another if it's 0 - 8. In that case you can use this:

```
{
    var feedback = Number( prompt("Please rate this game from 1 - 10."));

    if (feedback >= 9 && feedback <= 10)
    {
        console.log("Thank you!  We should race at the next concert!");
    }
    else if (feedback <=8)
    {
        console.log("I'll keep practicing coding and racing.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Watch out for that `else` statement without `if`! You need `else if` if you're going to provide another condition, otherwise the condition `(feedback <=8)` is the statement that gets run on `else`!

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things wrong with that code.

First, you don't need an expression after else.  'Else' just executes or not based on the initial if statement.  Because you have the "(feedback <= 8)" after else, the JS interpreter thinks that expression is all that needs done if the initial if statement is false.  It then executes the following console log, because it thinks it's out of the if/else block at that point.

Also, you need to use '==' or '===' instead of '=' in the if statement.  An '=' is used for setting a value, not for checking a value.  Because you put an '=' in an if statement you are setting Feedback to 10, which is not what you want.  That's a common error for new programmers.

Lastly, it's unclear what is supposed to happen when Feedback is 9.  I'll assume from your text that you want to treat it the same as 10, so you probably need to check '>=9' rather than '==10'.

The code should look like:

```
if(Feedback >= 9)
{
  console.log("Thank you!  We should race at the next concert!");
} 
else
{
  console.log("I'll keep practicing coding and racing.");
}
```